# Counting If Element Appears in Both Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, counting

I am trying to create a counter that increments `playerScores` for each player in `allPlayers` every time `allPlayers[i]` appears in `roundWinners`.

Currently `imJbVrPfGG` only raises to a count of `1` whereas it should be `3`.

**Arrays:**

`allPlayers = ["iMJbVrPfGG","PjCtgHizDF","iQtZ88qyeX","zhvd8mAdhl"]`

`roundWinners = ["iMJbVrPfGG","iMJbVrPfGG","iMJbVrPfGG"]`

**Code:**

```
for (i = 0; i < allPlayers.length; i++) {
    playersScores[i] = 0;
}
for (i = 0; i < roundWinners.length; i++) {
    if(roundWinners[i] == allPlayers[i]){
        var index = allPlayers.indexOf(roundWinners[i])
        playersScores[index]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there could be multiple matches per winner, you'll need an inner loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < allPlayers.length; i++) {
    playersScores[i] = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < roundWinners.length; j++) {
        if (roundWinners[j] == allPlayers[i]) playersScores[i]++;
    }
}
```

Result: `[3, 0, 0, 0]`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3pm0msh6/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have your if statement set up incorrectly.  Right now, you're incrementing your player index when you increment the round index... and comparing Spot 0 to Spot 0, Spot 1 to Spot 1.  Instead, you just need to look if the value exists in the array, and update the scores like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < allPlayers.length; i++) {
    playersScores[i] = 0;
}
for (i = 0; i < roundWinners.length; i++) {
    var index = allPlayers.indexOf(roundWinners[i])
    if(index >= 0) {
        playersScores[index]++;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, I have made the assumption that the `playerScores` array is maintained to be exactly in sync with the `allPlayers` array.

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops. The outer loop will go through each player and the inner loop will search and count all the matches. For example:

```
for (i = 0; i < allPlayers.length; i++) {
    playersScores[i] = 0;

    for (var j = 0; j < roundWinners.length; j++) { 
        if(roundWinners[j] == allPlayers[i]){
            playersScores[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```